# Laravel 5.4 Unserialize payload

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs

How do i unserialize the payload from a failed job?
Here is my situation:

I want to keep track of failed jobs, and notify the user... For that i use this snippet:

```
Queue::failing(function (JobFailed $event) {
            // $event->connectionName
            // $event->job
            // $event->exception
            LoggerFacade::addAlert("Error".$event->job->getRawBody());
        });
```

Works good, but i cannot fetch my meta data, like the feed id.

The serialized data look's like this:

```
 $json = '{"displayName":"Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\QueuedCommand","job":"Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler@call","maxTries":null,"timeout":null,"data":{"commandName":"Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\QueuedCommand","command":"O:43:\"Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\QueuedCommand\":1:{s:7:\"\u0000*\u0000data\";a:2:{i:0;s:11:\"import:feed\";i:1;a:1:{s:7:\"feed_id\";s:1:\"4\";}}}"}}';
```

I need this part

```
import:feed\";i:1;a:1:{s:7:\"feed_id\";s:1:\"4\";}}}
```

This `dd(unserialize($json));` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try first to do json decoding

```
 $json = json_decode($json);
 $data = unserialize($json['data']['command']);
```